# Azure B2C custom policy REST API CALL not working for Microsoft account

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have added Microsoft IDP to Custom Policy using this link [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account-custom?tabs=applications][1].
The user can click the Microsoft Account button and use their MSA account to sign-up\sign-in.
When the user signs up using MS acccount we'd like to validate the e-mail against our database. If the user's email is in our database, let them proceed and signup; otherwise we'd like to prevent them from signing up and display an error message. This would prevent creating a User in our Azure B2C AD.
I used the following TechnicalProfile in

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>live.com</Domain>
  <DisplayName>Microsoft Account</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="MSA-OIDC">
      <DisplayName>Microsoft Account</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ProviderName">https://login.live.com</Item>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.live.com/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">openid profile email</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">12344</Item>
      </Metadata>

      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_MSASecret" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-ValidateProfile" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
      </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

i added REST API Call

```
<ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
 <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-ValidateProfile" />
 </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
```

but is not working.
ANy idea?

Comment: Have you ensured your API is working as expected? Are you making it return [properly formated B2C error responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#returning-error-message)? Can you share your full policies?

Comment: Have the same problem. Have you been able to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you mentioned the Self Asserted Technical profile in ths custom policy which collects the user details submitted to b2c and you can validate the email using the REST API.

for more information you can through these articles

1. [REST API Claims exchange integration with user journey to validate user input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-claims-validation)
2. [LocalAndSocialAccount Sign In and Sign Up policy wiki](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/azureadb2ccommunity.io/wiki/LocalAndSocialAccount-Sign-In-and-Sign-Up-policy)

and there is a similar [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59623851/validate-and-verify-the-user-input-data-during-registration-using-custom-policy) related to validating the user input data